# Firebase functions: http function unable to read body or headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a simple function on my front-end which calls a firebase function on the back-end. Although the request and the API logic are very simple, the call always fails, because the firebase function is unable to detect either the body or the appropriate headers of the request.

Here is the front-end code:

```js
async function updateArtwork(
  artworkId: string,
  title: string,
  medium: string,
  description?: string,
  price?: number,
  printPrice?: number
): Promise<string> {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${config.apiUrl}updateArtwork`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        artworkId,
        title,
        description,
        price,
        printPrice,
        medium,
      }),
      headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
    });
    if (res) {
      return res.json();
    } else {
      throw new Error('Could not save changes to this artwork');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error('Could not save changes to this artwork');
  }
}
```

Here's the firebase function:

```js
export const updateArtwork = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (request, response) => {
    doChecks(request);
    const {
      artworkId,
      title,
      description,
      price,
      printPrice,
      medium,
    } = request.body;

    try {
      await db.collection('artworks').doc(artworkId).update({
        title,
        description,
        price,
        printPrice,
        medium,
      });
      return cors(request, response, () => {
        return response
          .status(200)
          .json('Successfully saved changes to artist');
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return response.status(500);
    }
  }
);
```

The function `doChecks()` just logs various things about the request to the console, including the headers and the body. Bafflingly, according to these logs `request.body` is `{}`, even though when I check the dev tools network tab, the body is populated. Similarly, the logs tell me that there is no `content-type` header on the request, while dev tools tells me the `content-type` is `application/json`, which is as expected.

In addition, the above call in the front-end makes two API calls, as opposed to the expected one. I know it does this because I did the following:

1. set a breakpoint on the `const res = await fetch...` line
2. hit that breakpoint and checked the dev tools network tab to confirm that no requests have yet been made
3. clicked "step over" in dev tools to step to the next line (`if (res)...`)
4. checked the network tab and saw two POST calls to the same endpoint

What makes this even more strange is that none of the above code has changed recently. It's possible that recent environment changes (upgrading npm packages, etc.) have somehow messed things up, but it's unclear what effect they would have.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

## EDIT

Here is more detail on the `doChecks()` function mentioned above. Here is the function:

```js
const doChecks = (request: any) => {
  console.log('request.body:');
  console.log(request.body);
  console.log('request.headers:');
  console.log(request.headers);
  console.log(`content type is ${request.headers['content-type']}`);
};
```

For the above call, here is what is logged:

```sh
>  request.body:
>  {}
>  request.headers:
>  {
>    host: 'localhost:5001',
>    connection: 'keep-alive',
>    accept: '*/*',
>    'access-control-request-method': 'POST',
>    'access-control-request-headers': 'content-type,pragma',
>    origin: 'http://localhost:3001',
>    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
>    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
>    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
>    referer: 'http://localhost:3001/cart',
>    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36',
>    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
>    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
>  }
>  content type is undefined
```

Comment: Can you add some more about the logs that show empty body?

Comment: @vitooh updated the OP with log output

Comment: Hey @GaiusDavidius! Sucks to hear you're having so much trouble with the HTTPS firebase function. Not sure if this will help in the future but firebase also has a Callable Function that's available right from your firebase SDK. Have a look here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable. It may help save you headaches in the future because it does alot of the the header checking and response wrapping for you :) Good luck out there!

Comment: @blaytenshi good to know, thanks! I think I'll give that a try

Answer (score 1):

After much tearing out of hair, I've found what looks to be the solution. I simply wrapped all the business logic of the firebase function inside the `cors()` call as below. None of the docs or examples I've seen have done this, so I'm not sure *why* this works. If anyone knows, please let me know!

```js
export const updateArtwork = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (request, response) => {
    return cors(request, response, async () => {
      try {
        const {
          artworkId,
          title,
          description,
          price,
          printPrice,
          medium,
        } = request.body;

        await db.collection('artworks').doc(artworkId).update({
          title,
          description,
          price,
          printPrice,
          medium,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        return cors(request, response, () => {
          response.status(500).end(err);
        });
      }
      response.status(200).send('Successfully saved changes to artist');
    });
  }
);
```